# Android - Creating a List like the Grocery IQ List

Tags: android, list, expandablelistview

(Using Android version 4.0.4)

I'm trying to build functionality very similar to the list found on the GroceryIQ app:

[image: GroceryIQ list]

I can create a nice looking list using the ExpandableListView shown in the xml below and a custom class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter, but I'm having trouble with the second list. Is it two lists with a view in between? Could this be just one list with a special list divider that just looks like a bar?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ExpList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp" />

<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/bottom_bar_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried adding another list, but two lists on one view don't seem to cooperate too well-- either the first list is chopped off or the second list doesn't show.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know that it's possible to know exactly how Grocery IQ crafted their list, but I found that I could replicate a pretty similar list by super-customizing the ExpandableListView.

An ExpandableListView is implemented using custom Group Items and Child Items.

I added a relative layout to the Group Item that looked like the "awesome bar". Then programmatically when I populated my list, I had a "rogue" Group Item that when I found it, I would show the "awesome bar" instead of the regular group-- in all the other cases the relative layout was set to invisible.

It took a while to get it "just right" and my solution seems a little like a hack, but that's the gist of what worked for me.